# Searching for local responsive sites

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

When designing responsive sites for customers, it would be nice to see what others have done, what works and what is ill-advised.  I'd love to be able to search for similar sites that are responsive, but can find very few, usually none.  The only option I know of is to google and then visit every site, checking to see if they're responsive.

I read not too long ago that Google was going to start putting a tag next to mobile-friendly sites in their listings.  Did that ever happen?  I'm not seeing it.  That would be VERY handy.

If I search for something like "responsive websites", I'll get compiled lists of the best responsive websites out there.  These are either incredibly artistic, or technological marvels, neither of which I'm looking for.  I'm interested in sites that are more run-of-the-mill.  Completely functional and responsive, but not awe-inspiring.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked this:

[collection of pages and theems {simple and complex too}](http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/index.php?theme=metronic)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm more interested in something like: "Landscapers near Massachusetts" (and show me only responsive sites.

Comment: I think the link I'd gave you provides very good responsive themes and pages. It helped me to know the good designs possibly it may help you just do some inner diggnig.

Comment: I appreciate it, but it's really not what I'm looking for.  Let's say that a local landscaper wants me to design a site for them and they're interested in responsive.  I want to see what other local landscapers have in a responsive site so that once I'm done, my customer doesn't come back and say "I thought I'd have a calendar of events section like Acme Landscaping has."  My clients often want to one-up the competition, or at the very least, not miss out on what they do.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Mobile-friendly tag is implemented but you can only see it on mobile devices.

[image: Google's "Mobile-friendly" tag]

Alternatively you can open the dev tools in Chrome and simulate a mobile device, which will also make Google show the tag.

Comment: That's interesting.  If I search for sites that I know are mobile friendly, I don't get that tag for any of them.  But I searched for "The Verge" and saw it.  I'm looking at results for sites that pass Google's mobile-friendly test.  I wonder what has to happen to get that label.

Comment: Can I ask a favor?  Could you search for "website design near boston"?  My results on my phone show no "mobile friendly" tagged sites.  However, a couple of highly rated companies, Jackrabbit Design and Going Clear Interactive, certainly appear to be responsive and mobile friendly.

Comment: Huh, that's weird. I see the Mobile-friendly tag for almost every entry on the first page of results, including Jackrabbit Design and Going Clear Interactive.